# Каноничный или канонический

Tags: прилагательные

Скажите, в чем разница и как правильно, каноничный или канонический?

Comment: Правильно — что? Какой текст или примеры смущают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Толковые словари видят *каноничный* синонимом переносного значения *канонический*. В этом смысле они употребляются в отрыве от церковного подтекста.

> Канонический
>
> 1. Установленный канонами церкви (церк.).
> 2. Входящий в состав канона (в 3 знач.; церк.).
> 3. перен. (в качестве кратк. употр. каноничен, канонична, канонично). Обязательный, твердо установленный, принятый за образец (книжн.).
>
> Каноничный (книжн.). То же, что канонический в 3 знач., согласный с каноном.
>
> — Толковый словарь Ушакова<sup>1</sup>

> Канонический
>
> 1. см. канон.
> 2. В текстологии: принятый за истинный, твёрдо установленный.
>
> Каноничный (книжн.). То же, что канонический (во 2 знач.).
>
> — Толковый словарь Ожегова<sup>2</sup>

> Канонический
>
> 1. соотн. с сущ. канон, связанный с ним
> 2. Свойственный канону, характерный для него.
> 3. Твёрдо установленный, принятый за образец.
>
> Каноничный Твёрдо установленный, принятый за образец; канонический 3.
>
> — Толковый словарь Ефремовой<sup>3</sup>

В добавление к словарям общей лексики: научные термины, как правило, используют *канонический*, нежели *каноничный*.

Что касается "правильности", то, как замечено [@shampar](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/4345/shampar), без контекста употребления сложно дать какой-либо комментарий.

---

1. Ушаков Д. Н., Винокур Г. О., проф. Ларин Б. А., Ожегов С. И., Томашевский Б. В. Толковый словарь русского языка под редакцией проф. Д. Н. Ушакова / Том I А–КЮРИНЫ — М: Государственный институт "Советская энциклопедия", ОГИЗ, 1935.
2. Ожегов С. И., Шведова Н. Ю. Толковый словарь русского языка — М.: Азъ, 1992.
3. Ефремова Т. Ф. Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный: В 2 т. — М.: Русский язык, 2000.